# How to fix pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to free space I allocated with the `malloc` function and yet every time I get this message:

> "malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeefbff510: pointer being freed was
>   not allocated"

even though I clearly allocated it with `malloc()`.

I've already tried sending `& manufacture` and just `manufacture`. I am pretty new to the entire memory allocation.

```
char* manufacture = (char*)malloc(15*sizeof(char));   
manufacture = "Suzuki"; 

free(manufacture);
```

Comment: by doing `manufacture = "Suzuki";` you're changing where `manufacture` points to a block of memory that was not `malloc`ed. You want to use [`strcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to store "Suzuki" in your newly `malloc`ed block. Also, always check the return of `malloc` to make sure it allocated memory for you.

Answer (score 6):

Though you allocate memory with `malloc` and assign the address of this memory to a pointer, you overwrite this pointer in the second statement and let it point to a string literal. Note: with `manufacture = "Suzuki";`, the string literal is *not* copied into the memory block you reserved; you just let the pointer point to something different.

Your code is actually doing something like `free("Suzuki")`, which is clearly freeing something that has not been "malloced" before.

Write...

```
char* manufacture = (char*)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
strcpy(manufacture,"Suzuki");
...
free(manufacture);
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you are losing your allocated memory when you are doing

```
manufacture = "Suzuki";
```

Your string "Suzuki" here is an area of 7 bytes ( 6 + '\0' ). And manufacture points to this area when you assign it like this.

You can do something like this

```
manufacture = malloc(sizeof char * 7);
if (manufacture != NULL)
{
    free(manufacture);
}
```

( Yes, malloc can fail, check for errors )

And then if you want to copy some data in the allocated area, you have to use functions like strcpy, strncpy, memcpy, etc. Here strcpy is the right tool :

```
manufacture = malloc(sizeof char * 7);
if (manufacture != NULL)
{
    strcpy(manufacture, "Suzuki");
    free(manufacture);
}
```